# How Linux Shell identifies the short and long options for a corresponding command to be same?

Tags: shell

I am trying to write a shell script which takes command line arguments which will be parsed using "getopts" command in the script, I would like to make sure that in my script short and long options works same i,e -i and --isite works same, please help me in achieving it.

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with the kernel; It has *everything* to do with the standard library you're using. Whether `-h` and `--help` work the same is *completely* up to you. Without specifying a language, this question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you are creating your own script which take options and perform accordingly.

To achieve short and long options for a command use or option.
e.g.

> case $1 in
>
> -l|--list)
>        statement ;;
>
> esac

where $1 is your option.

here your statement will get executed for both option -l and --list.

Comment: Thank u...but i want to achieve the same using "getopt" command instead of $1...so a little more help would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using 'getopts', and not 'getopt' which is obsolete.  Also this is only valid in Korn Shell, as far as I'm aware.

Then the script line

```
getopts "f:(file)l(long)"
```

will equate -f with --file, and -l with --long.

All this is documented in the `man getopts` manual page on your system.